# Mysql statement give null

Tags: c#, mysql

I get in statement null but the id exists in database in the correct column and with the same name....

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT name FROM user WHERE IDS = 'AB18x55gin'", conn);
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
string name = Convert.ToString(result);
```

i dont know why i get null but the name is "name" and IDS is "AB18x55gin" in the row if i select the same statement in phpMyAdmin it works and give me the name but not in c# help please

Comment: Then you're connecting to a different instance or selecting from a different database.

Comment: No its the same database

Comment: @Pikoh   thanks but dont work :(

Answer (score 1):

Your query might be failing because `user` is  a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL, you should wrap the columns the table name in square brackets like (which is a good practice):

```
SELECT [name] FROM [user] WHERE [IDS] = 'AB18x55gin'
```

Hope this helps!